# Is there any way to stop ADB from automatically trying to connect to ANY android device plugged in?

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, adb

So here's the thing. I use MyPhoneExplorer in USB mode which uses ADB to communicate with the phone. Whenever my phone is connected (using MyPhoneExplorer) and try to test an app in eclipse on my EMULATOR, ADB crashes, rendering both MPE and the emulator useless.

My question is: Is there any way to prevent adb from accessing one phone from multiple sources? (In this case its trying to access the phone for both Eclipse and MPE).

Weird/Confusing question I know, but would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I assume you're on Windows?  (it might be relevant to the answer)

Comment: Yeah. Haven't tested this scenario on the iMac. Will do so Monday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but how about directing ABD at a given device with this:

```
adb -s <serialNumber> <command>
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#directingcommands

Use `adb devices` to find out the serial number of your emulator.

But from what you describe it might be that ADB's device detection that's breaking things.